# Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `PageController` inside of `ChangeNotifier` as my App Provider model. I want to change page view in another screen or widget as module with change `PageView` index value to this pageController. This model is working well. But when user logouts from another page view (settings), app will navigate to `"/"` route, after user authentication it will push to a screen that handle 5 page inside of `PageView` like following:

```dart
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => appTabHandlerProvider.systemPopNavigation(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: appTabHandlerProvider.pageController,
          children: const [
            HomeScreen(),
            UserTraffic(),
            ReserveCategories(),
            UserPlates(),
            SettingsScreen(),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: navigationBar,
      ),
    );
```

But at this level user can't change page view and will get following error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 106 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      ScrollController.position (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:106:12)
#3      PageController.jumpToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:211:41)
#4      AppTabHandlerProvider.setNewPageControllerIndex= (package:mci_parking/modules/app/provider/app_provider.dart:29:20)
#5      _AppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mci_parking/modules/app/screen/app_tab_handler.dart:71:31)
#6      NavigationBar._handleTap.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/navigation_bar.dart:207:37)
#7      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1154:21)
#8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
#9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:654:11)
#10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:311:5)
#11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:281:7)
#12     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:167:27)
#13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:469:20)
#14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:445:22)
#15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:331:11)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:400:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:363:5)
#18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:320:7)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:293:9)
#20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:158:13)
#21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:382:7)
#22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#a5bc4
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

User can change view by close and open application, after that `PageController` works well.

Here is my AppProvider model:

```dart
/// # App Tab Handler Provider
///
/// Provides state of BottomNavigationBar.
class AppTabHandlerProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  /// Bottom tab bar index
  late int bottomNavigationIndex = 0;

  /// Tab bar controller. A glue between [PageView] and [BottomNavigationBar].
  late PageController pageController = PageController();

  void initState() {
    bottomNavigationIndex = 0;
  }

  /// Dispose page controller after app exit
  void get disposePageController {
    pageController.dispose();
    bottomNavigationIndex = 0;
  }

  /// Sets new tab index to change page view
  set setNewPageControllerIndex(int index) {
    // Changes ui controller
    bottomNavigationIndex = index;
    pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// # System Pop Navigation
  ///
  /// Connects bottom Navigation buttons to system navigation pop button. Fixes
  /// behavior of SystemPopNavigationButton to BottomNavigationButtons.
  systemPopNavigation() {
    if (bottomNavigationIndex >= 1 && bottomNavigationIndex <= 4) {
      setNewPageControllerIndex = 0;
    } else {
      // Pops and exits from App
      SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod("SystemNavigator.pop");
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Yes I know that we can use `PageController` as a `ChangeNotifier` and add it to our list of providers, But after try that, I got same error:

```
Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
```

I'm using Flutter stable version `3.10.3` and dart version `3.0.3`.

Comment: Are you using the same controller for more than one listview ou tabBarview?these pageview children are not using any controller?

Comment: @IldebertoVasconcelos I have been using `controller: appTabHandlerProvider.pageController` at `PageView` widget, it is exists in my above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't proper way. I fixed it by `auto_router` strategies instead of PageController.

```dart
return AutoTabsRouter(
  routes: const [
    HomeRoute(),
    UserTrafficRoute(),
    ReservesRoute(),
    PlatesRoute(),
    SettingsRoute(),
  ],
  builder: (context, child) {
    final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => appTabHandlerProvider.systemPopNavigation(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: child,
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
          height: 80.0,
          selectedIndex: appTabHandlerProvider.bottomNavigationIndex,
          onDestinationSelected: (int navigationIndex) {
            tabsRouter.setActiveIndex(navigationIndex);
            appTabHandlerProvider.setNewTabIndex = navigationIndex;
          },
          destinations: AppNamespace.navigationBarItem
              .map(
                (NavigationBarChild navigationChildItem) =>
                    NavigationDestination(
                  icon: navigationChildItem.selectedIcon,
                  selectedIcon: navigationChildItem.selectedIcon,
                  label: t.translate(navigationChildItem.label),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```